# pixi.js rendering not working

Tags: rendering, pixi.js

I am following along with a tutorial (http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=5226) and when I try to render on google chrome the dev tools console shows this:

```
Pixi.js v2.2.3 - webGL      http://www.pixijs.com/    ♥♥♥     pixi.dev.is:224
```

referring to line# 224 on the pixi source code:

```
line# 224    console.log.apply(console, args);
```

this is my code(:

```
function init(){
    stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x66FF99);
    renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(
    512,
    384,
    document.getElementById("game-canvas")
    );
    renderer.render(stage);
}
```

Comment: Did you add `onload="init();"` to your body tag. Also are there any errors in console?

Comment: Yes onload="init(); is in the body tag and no errors are showing

Comment: Did you set up a local server. Pixijs will not work properly if you are accessing your files directly.